# How to include the TensorFlow object detection API into my Python project?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the [TensorFlow object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) in a Python project. In order to run the code in PyCharm I include the location of the TensorFlow git repository's `models/research` directory as a "Content Root". When I run the code at command line I include this directory location in `PYTHONPATH`. This is simple enough, but I'd like to eliminate the need for users to take care of this legwork if it's possible to have the TensorFlow `object-detection` module installed into the environment along with the other dependencies of my project's [package](https://github.com/monocongo/cvdata).

I have tried adding the following to my `requirements.txt` to no avail (i.e. `pip install requirements.txt` hangs):

```
-e git+https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git#egg=research
```

I have also tried reading all lines from `requirements.txt` in `setup.py` for dependency links, but using this approach doesn't work either when I run `python setup.py install`.

In the [Object Detection API Demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) there is a clone of the repository and then an install via

```
cd models/research
pip install .
```

Can something like this be done via an appropriate entry in the `requirements.txt` and/or some code in the `setup.py` of my project?

My goal is to not get a ModuleNotFoundError when my code calls `import object_detection`, etc. if users haven't already installed the TensorFlow object detection API into their Python environment "by hand".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `egg=...` parameter is used only to tell `pip` the name of the module. To install from the `research` subdirectory of the repository, append another parameter:

```
## requirements.txt
-e git+https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git#egg=research&subdirectory=research
```

And in the command line:

```
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git#egg=research\&subdirectory=research
```

(note the escaped `&` as it is a special character in most shells).

Comment: Thank you, @Seb, very helpful! This gets me almost all the way home. Unfortunately, I still need to somehow automate the protobuf compilation (as described here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#protobuf-compilation) otherwise I get the following error: >>> from object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util
Traceback (most recent call last):
    from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2'

Comment: Which platforms will your users install this on? Would it be acceptable to just have a script (say, `install.sh`) that automates the installation?

Comment: This is a very good idea, I haven't thought of that. I have managed to purge my dependency on that protobuf (string_int_label_map_pb2) so now it's just down to installing the TFOD API from GitHub. I discovered that you can't use the solution in the answer within `setup.py` so there's always going to be that extra step involved besides the pip install from PyPI. Here's how I have things now, please advise if you think there's a better way to skin this cat: https://github.com/monocongo/cvdata#installation

Comment: Looks good to me! Just be aware that depending directly on another repository can of course always lead to stuff in your project breaking unless you specify a specific point in the target's commit history. I would consider the alternative of adding the `tensorflow` repository as a submodule in your own. This way you should be able to skip the extra step in the installation as it will be part of your project, and have full control over the compatibility between your code base and the tensorflow repository as you can update the submodule in line with your supporting commits.